# FME metafile multi-writer could not be opened

Tags: fme-form

I run a workflow and FME showed me that message :

> 2019-08-23 12:46:05|   1.9|  0.0|ERROR |BADNEWS: File C:\Program
>   Files\FME\metafile\MULTI_WRITER.fmf could not be opened
>   (tabrdr.cpp:161)

It is the very first time I come across that, I don't understand why

Comment: Did the translation actually fail at that point or did it carry on? My hunch is that this is not a real error and potentially we should suppress it -- it is artifact of some internal plumbing.

Comment: Can you please add the version and build number for this question.

Comment: related: https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/44058/badnews-file-dappsfmemetafilemulti-writerfmf-could.html

Answer (score 2):

Your logging level is probably at debug. Set it one level less detailed and it wont show up again. Often these "BADNEWS" messages can be ignored.

You can find this via Tools, Options, tab Translation, "Log Message Filter".

[image]